# Before-insert trigger based on job categories

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

Good day,
I am trying to create a trigger that should retrieve the total number of users based on their job category (medic/other) into two parameters for all users who have registered so I developed:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER count_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON REGISTRATION_FORM
    FOR EACH ROW

    DECLARE
    p_current_doctor_number varchar2(20);
    p_current_other_number varchar2(20);
    p_ann_id number;

   BEGIN

-- Count the existing trainees based on medical job category
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REGISTRATION_FORM INTO p_current_doctor_number
WHERE JOB_CATEGORY = 'Medic'
AND ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_ann_id;

 -- Count the existing trainees based on other job category
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TRN_LS_REGISTRATION_FORM INTO p_current_other_number
 WHERE JOB_CATEGORY != 'Medic'
 AND ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_ann_id;
```

but I received the below error:

```
 Trigger COUNT_BEFORE_INSERT compiled

 LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
9/4       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/50      PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
14/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/50     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: you commented that you will use a trigger to select data into page items. That could work but it is not a good practice. I'd recommend using a stored procedure or a function for this.

Comment: @Koen Lostrie Thanks for ur advice, I tried to retrieve data directly from source using plsql function but sadly the page item is not consciously updated, any suggestion is appreciated and thanks again.

Comment: hard to give you advice with such little information. It should always work with pl/sql or sql as a source - if you can create a testcase on apex.oracle.com, or create a new question about this i'm happy to take a look. Trigger should be avoided for this - it will be come a maintenance nightmare and a complete mystery for the developer who comes after you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `SELECT - INTO - FROM`, not `SELECT - FROM - INTO`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER count_before_insert
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON REGISTRATION_FORM
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   p_current_doctor_number  VARCHAR2 (20);
   p_current_other_number   VARCHAR2 (20);
   p_ann_id                 NUMBER;
BEGIN
   -- Count the existing trainees based on medical job category
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO p_current_doctor_number
     FROM REGISTRATION_FORM
    WHERE     JOB_CATEGORY = 'Medic'
          AND ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_ann_id;

   -- Count the existing trainees based on other job category
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO p_current_other_number
     FROM TRN_LS_REGISTRATION_FORM
    WHERE     JOB_CATEGORY != 'Medic'
          AND ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_ann_id;
END;
```

Now, the trigger doesn't do anything *smart* so I presume that there's something more you'll be doing here.

Beware of mutating table error (you can't select data from a table that is just being modified).

Also, `p_ann_id` is a local variable which is currently `NULL` so those selects won't return anything. Perhaps you meant to use

```
... and ANNOUCMENT_ID = :new.ANNOUCMENT_ID
```

Comment: thanks again for ur continuous help & support, I agree with u 100% but those data will be retrieved into two page items after that will be used in IF statement to check if the current users reach the maximum number of allowed users. Thank u again for ur huge help